# Access control is not enabled for the database

Tags: mongodb

I am creating an sample library app in nodejs+express+mongodb. when I run the gulp serve command the server start perfectly. when I goto specific mongodb page then it giving error insertMany is not a function.

```
var express = require('express');
var adminRouter = express.Router();
var mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var books = [
   {
      title: 'world',
      genre: 'Lorem Ipsum text changing occured',
      author: 'Rakesh',
      read: false
   },
   {
      title: 'Make of the world',
      genre: 'Digital India towards occured',
      author: 'Jumanji',
      read: false
   }
];

var router = function (nav) {
   adminRouter.route('/addBooks')
      .get(function (req, res) {
         var url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin';
         mongodb.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            var collections = db.collections('books');
            collections.insertMany(books, 
               function (err, results) {
                  res.send(results);
                  db.close();
               }
            );
         });
      });

   return adminRouter;
};

module.exports = router;
```

[Mongo cmd screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJwVn.jpg)
[insertMany cmd not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTmFm.jpg)

Comment: `var collections = db.collections('books');` should be `.collection`. As in `var collections = db.collection('books');` And you really should be using `db.collection('books',function(err,collection) {` In order to trap errors.

Comment: The message in the screenshot is from connecting to the shell and unrelated to the code in the question. It is a default "warning" to you that you "should" be enabling access control, if you don't want unauthorized users accessing and altering your database.

Comment: Images are useful in a post, but **make sure the post is still clear without them**. Instead of showing a screenshot of your data format, copy and paste or type the actual data into the post directly.
cf http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in syntax in line `var collections = db.collections('books');`.  The node mongo driver could only interpret a db.collection() function not db.collections() which actually is syntactically wrong.

Use `db.collection('books')` instead of `db.collections('books')`, this should fix the bug. Try it and let me know

Comment: great! if it works, do accept the answer so that this would help others to fix issues as such :P